# Serialising a JavaScript CanvasRenderingContext2D states array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to serialise a canvas' state for saving to a database which could be restored at a later time. I want to save the data as an object instead of a bitmap file.

My understanding `.save()` and `.restore()` on the context object will manipulate the current stack, although is it possible to serialise the stack itself? I cant find any way to access the stack directly on the interface `CanvasRenderingContext2D` [API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#canvasrenderingcontext2d)

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The save/restore is a [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_(computing)) stack. It only saves states, no content or path. Do I read you correctly by that you want to save the *entire* stack, and not only the last (current)?

Comment: Sorry @user13500 i'm still teaching myself about the canvas element as I work through this. My understanding is there is a stack of `drawing states` [link](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#drawing-state) I want to serialise the **whole stack** as to recreate the same canvas drawing at a later time from the database. From what i've interpreted each drawing state holds data on a paths properties which create the path and content? Although i'm unable to find any way to pop an object of the stack to serialise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save/restore is a [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29) stack. It only [saves states](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas_CR/#the-canvas-state), no content or path.

The stack itself can not be retrieved. Upon a `.restore()` when we are at the bottom of the stack is silently ignored.

It does not save any image data, paths etc. As such you cannot, even if you could retrieve the whole stack, use it to re-create a drawing. All you would get was e.g.:

```
stack[0] { fillStyle : #000000, textAlign: start, ... }
stack[1] { fillStyle : #aabb33, textAlign: middle, ... }
stack[2] { ... }
```

What you could save is the image data. For example [by using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Methods):

- [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Methods), `canvas.toDataURL('image/png');`
- [toBlob()](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-toblob)*

Note that *toBlob()* is [widely unsupported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Browser_support).

One could also use [*getImageData()*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-getimagedata) if one would want the raw RGB bits.

Also check out e.g. *createImageData()*, *putImageData()*, *drawImage()*.

---

As for the stack:

The properties that could be retrieved and saved off-canvas are the attributes such as *fillStyle* and *font*.

If we dump the context object we get, for example in Chrome:

```
                      canvas : [object HTMLCanvasElement]
                         arc : function arc() { [native code] }
                         ... : function ...

#--- Webkit specific:
                 currentPath : {} # Empty even with path.
webkitBackingStorePixelRatio : 1
 webkitImageSmoothingEnabled : true

#--- Attributes part of save() / restore():

                   fillStyle : #000000
                        font : 10px sans-serif
                 globalAlpha : 1
    globalCompositeOperation : source-over
       imageSmoothingEnabled : true
                     lineCap : butt
              lineDashOffset : 0
                    lineJoin : miter
                   lineWidth : 1
                  miterLimit : 10
                  shadowBlur : 0
                 shadowColor : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
               shadowOffsetX : 0
               shadowOffsetY : 0
                 strokeStyle : #000000
                   textAlign : start
                textBaseline : alphabetic
```

The attributes could be retrieved by specifying them directly, or by doing a *for in* loop and checking *typeof*. But the use of this information would be rather limited when retrieved from e.g. a file or database.

One would also miss out on transformation matrix, clipping region etc.

Comment: Thanks! This has assisted my understanding, appreciate the in depth reply